# getting 403 when trying to post a file in gcp storage using react js if file already exists

Tags: reactjs, post, google-cloud-platform, axios

I am trying to upload a file in GCP(google cloud) bucket from reactjs using the following code snippet

`yield rawAxios.post(response.data.resumable_upload_url, dataBlob, {                     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/png' },                     onUploadProgress(progress) {},                 });`

It works fine if the file does not exist in that storage location.
But I get a 403 forbidden error if the file already exists in that location.

Is there any setting that I need to enable in my storage bucket?
I would appreciate it if anyone can help me here. Thanks in advance

When I delete the file manually from that location in GCP and try to upload again using reactjs it works fine

Comment: @GRD - where does the documentation say that a resumable upload must be unique? Resumable uploads can replace an existing object. **Only a completed resumable upload appears in your bucket and, if applicable, replaces an existing object with the same name.** https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads

Comment: Which roles are assigned to the service account? See the answer from @francesco-clementi

Answer (score 2):

As shown in google cloud storage [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions), your service account need:

*Note: In order to replace existing objects, both storage.objects.create and storage.objects.delete permissions are required.*